# Network structure recognition with python

Tags: python, sorting, networking, raspberry-pi, treeview

I have the problem that I have to recognise the structure of a "flat" network (all devices in the same address space 192.168.10.0). The individual devices are Raspberry Pi's which are configured as Brides. Through the bridge-utils, I can read out the mac addresses of the previous devices. Thus I have given the crossed nodes for each device.

Now I want to use an algorithm to recognise the structure from these mac addresses. The following picture shows the structure I am looking for:
[searched network structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ClZ8d.png)

The following is a list of the passed nodes for each device (SBx stands for sensor box):

```
SB1:   mac0
SB2:   mac0, mac1
SB3:   mac0, mac1, mac2
SB4:   mac0, mac1
SB5:   mac0, mac1, mac4
SB6:   mac0, mac1, mac2
SB7:   mac0, mac1, mac4
```

My approach so far is as follows:

```
nodes = []
(nodes, boxes) = self.__get_sorted_nodes()

# for the shift through the branches
n = []
n1_cnt = []
n2_cnt = []
for key, value in dict(Counter(map(len, nodes))).items(): 
    n.append(value)
n1_cnt = n[:]
n1_cnt.insert(0,0)
del n1_cnt[len(n1_cnt)-1]

n2_cnt = n[:]
del n2_cnt[0]
n2_cnt.append(0)

for i in range(max_step):
    if i == max_length:
        break
            
    print(f'--- Step {i+1} -----------------------')
        for j, n1 in enumerate(nodes[i+n1_cnt[i]]):
        print(f'Node (higher) {j}: {n1}')
            for t in range(n2_cnt[i]):
                for k, n2 in enumerate(nodes[i+t+1]):
                    print(f'Node (lower) {k}: {n2}')
                        if n1 in n2:
                            self.__connect_nodes(n1, n2)
                print(f'----------------------------------')
```

```
max_step   # max count of the structure steps
max_length # list with the quantity of nodes per step (e.g. in this examples 2 nodes on step 1 --> SB2 and SB4)
nodes      # 2D list with all passed mac addresses per node (list is sorted by length)
```

In a daisy chain configuration it works but as soon as there is a branch there are problems.

Thank you for your help.
Greetings Michael

Comment: maybe you should use some module [anytree](https://anytree.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) or  [networkx](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/auto_examples/drawing/plot_custom_node_icons.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-drawing-plot-custom-node-icons-py)

Comment: @furas thanks for your answer. Visualization with anytree or networkx is the next step. I need to find out the topology of the boxes before I can visualize this.